# Java throws "Repository Does Not Have Release File" when running apt-get update on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: java, ubuntu

Whenever I try to run `apt-get update` in my Ubuntu 19.10 machine, I get the error `E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.`

I have installed OpenJDK v 13 on this machine and can use Java commands with no issue, including my IDE's.

Java version as shown by `java --version` shows me this:

`openjdk 13 2019-09-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13+33-Ubuntu-1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13+33-Ubuntu-1, mixed mode)`

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like there are no packages in the repository for your version of Ubuntu

Comment: Go to [repo dists](http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/) You can see `eoan` is missing.